# Prometheus Operator: Can't access Prometheus instance

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, dock, prometheus-operator

I am following the [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#include-servicemonitors) to create services operator. I am not sure why I cannot access the Prometheus services.

My apps.yml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sms-config-service
  labels:
    app: sms-config-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sms-config-service
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http
```

My ServiceMonitor yml:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: servicemonitor-sms-services
  name: servicemonitor-sms-config-services
  namespace: metrics
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sms-config-service
  endpoints:
    - port: http
```

Prometheus yml:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: servicemonitor-sms-services
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 800Mi
  enableAdminAPI: true
```

Prometheus config yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: web
      nodePort: 30900
      port: 9090
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: web
  selector:
    prometheus: prometheus
```

When I access the url below, browser shows "unable to connect". I am not sure where I did wrong? Should I set up a deployment for the Prometheus?

---

```
$ minikube service prometheus --url
http://192.168.64.3:30900
```

Update:
I have the prometheus pod running on NodePort 32676.
[image]
Should I change the Prometheus config yml to fix the issue?

Comment: Prometheus pods are up and running? Any error in prometheus pod logs?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Hi, I can access Prometheus at http://localhost:9090/graph So, prometheus is running?

Comment: Okay could be a networking issue in minikube..any other nodeport service access works?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I think may be a config issue? Yes, the access to my app (sms-config-service) works.

Comment: Oh, I am running Prometheus using `./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml`. Is this the cause? In this way, the running prometheus isn't in kubernete cluster.

Comment: Prometheus needs to run as a pod so that the service can forward the traffic to that pod. You can't use kubernetes service to route traffic to something which is running outside kubernetes

Comment: Thanks Arghya! I just realized I have Prometheus running in pods(I am using kube-prometheus-stack). I can access the Prometheus through `http://192.168.64.3:32676/graph`. Should I change a IP in `Prometheus config yml` to 32676? Thanks! @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: nvm, I find the issue is I don't have serviceAccountName created.

Comment: Another potential issue is in your Service monitor spec. It needs a namespace selector to select service endpoints from the correct namespace. https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#servicemonitorspec

Answer (score 4):

I find the issue is I don't have `serviceAccountName` created.